# Marshal and Unmarshal a time.Time, Got different values

Tags: json, go

I am try to update my Go code from 1.8 to 1.9. but, i got some problem:

```
package simple_struct

import (
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
)

type SimpleStruct struct {
    CreateTime time.Time
    Other      string
}

func NewSimpleStruct() *SimpleStruct {
    return &SimpleStruct{
        CreateTime: time.Now(),
    }
}

func Test(t *testing.T) {
    s1 := NewSimpleStruct()
    data, err := json.Marshal(s1)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    s2 := &SimpleStruct{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, s2)
    assert.Nil(t, err)

    assert.Equal(t, s2, s1)
    // this is not equal
    // output:
    /*

    Diff:
    --- Expected
    +++ Actual
    @@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
    (*simple_struct.SimpleStruct)({
        - CreateTime: (time.Time) 2017-12-01 14:54:53.948875421 +0800 CST,
        + CreateTime: (time.Time) 2017-12-01 14:54:53.948875421 +0800 CST m=+0.001827244,
    */
}
```

It is working in Golang 1.8, but not in Golang 1.9.

I know that Golang 1.9 has update `time.Time`, but I do not understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably to do with monotonic time being wiped by marshalling. See the the package docs

Answer (score 3):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> `import "time"`
>
> Note that the Go == operator compares not just the time instant but
>   also the Location and the monotonic clock reading.
>
> [func (Time) Equal](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal)
>
> `func (t Time) Equal(u Time) bool`
>
> Equal reports whether t and u represent the same time instant. Two
>   times can be equal even if they are in different locations. For
>   example, 6:00 +0200 CEST and 4:00 UTC are Equal. See the documentation
>   on the Time type for the pitfalls of using == with Time values; most
>   code should use Equal instead.

---

```
// A Time represents an instant in time with nanosecond precision.
//
// Time instants can be compared using the Before, After, and Equal methods.
//
// Note that the Go == operator compares not just the time instant but also the
// Location and the monotonic clock reading. Therefore, Time values should not
// be used as map or database keys without first guaranteeing that the
// identical Location has been set for all values, which can be achieved
// through use of the UTC or Local method, and that the monotonic clock reading
// has been stripped by setting t = t.Round(0). In general, prefer t.Equal(u)
// to t == u, since t.Equal uses the most accurate comparison available and
// correctly handles the case when only one of its arguments has a monotonic
// clock reading.
//
type Time struct {
// wall and ext encode the wall time seconds, wall time nanoseconds,
// and optional monotonic clock reading in nanoseconds.
//
// From high to low bit position, wall encodes a 1-bit flag (hasMonotonic),
// a 33-bit seconds field, and a 30-bit wall time nanoseconds field.
// The nanoseconds field is in the range [0, 999999999].
// If the hasMonotonic bit is 0, then the 33-bit field must be zero
// and the full signed 64-bit wall seconds since Jan 1 year 1 is stored in ext.
// If the hasMonotonic bit is 1, then the 33-bit field holds a 33-bit
// unsigned wall seconds since Jan 1 year 1885, and ext holds a
// signed 64-bit monotonic clock reading, nanoseconds since process start.
wall uint64
ext  int64

// loc specifies the Location that should be used to
// determine the minute, hour, month, day, and year
// that correspond to this Time.
// The nil location means UTC.
// All UTC times are represented with loc==nil, never loc==&utcLoc.
loc *Location
}
```

---

It has long been the case, not just now (go1.9 +), that it is wrong to compare Go `time.Time`s by comparing the implementation (opaque `struct`) with the Go equal operator (`==`). For example, as far back as go1.4,

> Note that the Go `==` operator compares not just the time instant but
>   also the Location. Therefore, Time values should not be used as map or
>   database keys without first guaranteeing that the identical Location
>   has been set for all values, which can be achieved through use of the
>   UTC or Local method.

go1.9 merely added an additional element, a monotonic value, to the opaque `time.Time` `struct`.

---

Always use the `time.Equal` method to assert `time.Time` equality.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now() // wall, location, & monotonic
    fmt.Println("Now:   ", now)
    clock := now.Round(0) // wall & location
    fmt.Println("Clock: ", clock)
    utc := now.UTC() // wall & location UTC
    fmt.Println("UTC:   ", utc)
    fmt.Println("now.Equal(clock)", now.Equal(clock)) // true
    fmt.Println("now == clock    ", now == clock)     // false
    fmt.Println("now.Equal(utc)  ", now.Equal(utc))   // true
    fmt.Println("now == utc      ", now == utc)       // false
    fmt.Println("clock.Equal(utc)", clock.Equal(utc)) // true
    fmt.Println("clock == utc    ", clock == utc)     // false
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/VbFV2AcYw-

Output:

```
Now:    2017-12-01 14:54:15.168706745 -0500 EST m=+0.000899521
Clock:  2017-12-01 14:54:15.168706745 -0500 EST
UTC:    2017-12-01 19:54:15.168706745 +0000 UTC
now.Equal(clock) true
now == clock     false
now.Equal(utc)   true
now == utc       false
clock.Equal(utc) true
clock == utc     false
```